# line 1: syntax error: unexpected word (expecting ")") for chromedriver when its trying run from Docker

Tags: java, windows, docker, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Can you help me out to resolve the issue. Thanks in advanace

Getting syntax error: unexpected word (expecting ")" when its trying to launch chromedriver from the Docker. I used this docker command and desired capabillites for chrome

1. `docker run -it --name=test -e XML_FILE=/app/scenarios.xml --net=host testing-adh`

   ```
       HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
       chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
       String downloadpath = dir+File.separator+"src" + File.separator + "main"
               + File.separator + "resources" + File.separator +"files";
       chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory",downloadpath);
       ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
       options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);

       DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
       capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
       capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
       capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, configProp.getProperty("platform"));
       String chromepath=System.getProperty("user.dir")+File.separator+"chromedriver.exe";
       System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromepath);
       webDriver driver =new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
   ```

Comment: hey, its your chrome drivers causing the issue: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads  get another version from here

Answer (score 0):

```
String chromepath=System.getProperty("user.dir")+File.separator+"chromedriver.exe";
```

the `chromepath` return value with wrong file separators for Docker

I think the problem is in file separators, your file separators should be like this
`foo/foo1/foo.exe` instead of `foo\foo1\foo.exe`